# Android UnityPlayerActivity Action Bar

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I am building an Android application which includes a Unity 3d interactive experience.

I have imported the Unity project into Android Studio but when launched the activity is fullscreen and does not show the Android action bar.

How can I do this?

**Integration Steps**

- Create new Unity project.
- Export "Google Android Project" from Unity.
- Import project into Android Studio.

**Attempted Solutions**

- Changing the theme in the manifest.
- Setting the theme in the UnityPlayerActivity Java class.
- Overriding the Unity Android Manifest by placing a manifest with an updated theme in the Unity directory /Assets/Plugins/Android.
- Changing UnityPlayerActivity to extend AppCompatActivity. This will show the action bar but there is a white gap between it and the status bar.
- Setting "Screen.fullScreen = false;" in Unity SceneManager. This removes the immersive mode so that the Android status bar is visible.
- Turning off "Status Bar Hidden" in player settings. Appears to have no effect.
- Wrapping the UnityPlayer in a FrameLayout. This allows me to resize the the Unity as a view.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.unity.test"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:banner="@drawable/app_banner"
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:isGame="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <activity
            android:name="com.company.unity.test.UnityPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
                android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
        android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

UnityPlayerActivity.java

```
package com.company.unity.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Window;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

public class UnityPlayerActivity extends Activity
{
    protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer; // don't change the name of this variable; referenced from native code

    // Setup activity layout
    @Override protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888); // <--- This makes xperia play happy

        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        setContentView(mUnityPlayer);
        mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
    }

    // Quit Unity
    @Override protected void onDestroy ()
    {
        mUnityPlayer.quit();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    // Pause Unity
    @Override protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        mUnityPlayer.pause();
    }

    // Resume Unity
    @Override protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mUnityPlayer.resume();
    }

    // This ensures the layout will be correct.
    @Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    // Notify Unity of the focus change.
    @Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }

    // For some reason the multiple keyevent type is not supported by the ndk.
    // Force event injection by overriding dispatchKeyEvent().
    @Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE)
            return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    // Pass any events not handled by (unfocused) views straight to UnityPlayer
    @Override public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)     { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
    @Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)          { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
    /*API12*/ public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)  { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
}
```

Comment: I wrote you changed theme in manifest but in example one there's @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen. Is this a theme you changed to? If not then what was it?

Comment: @Lingviston The code I posted shows the original integration. I tried changing the theme to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar"` on both application and activity tags but neither made the action bar visible.

Comment: @Morepork have you found solution?

Comment: @Piotr Unfortunately no not yet, I did discover an app called Sailknowledge Compact (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.WATAP.SailknowledgeCompact) which looks like it does this and have been in contact with the developer about this on the Unity forums (http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/keeping-unity-player-alive-to-reuse-in-other-view.248361/) but communications have stalled.

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue. I tried all your methods + using getWindow().clearFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN ) but without effect :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found solution.
Change that line:

```
mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
```

so it creates your own `UnityPlayer` subclass, which overrides `setFullscreen` method (little bit hacky):

```
public class UnityPlayerWrapper extends UnityPlayer {
    public UnityPlayerWrapper(ContextWrapper contextWrapper) {
        super(contextWrapper);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setFullscreen(boolean b) {
        super.setFullscreen(false);
    }
}
```

In addition, please remove that line: `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: I tried this in my project but I'm not seeing an action bar. Tested on a Samsung Galaxy S6 running Android 5.1.1.

Comment: have you disabled that line as well - requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); ?

Comment: Working after disabling the no title feature. Thanks @Piotr.

Comment: @Piotr What version of Unity do you use? UnityPlayer has no method named `setFullscreen` on my version (5.5.0f3).

Comment: @Dalmas I think it was 5.3.5 that time.

Answer (score 6):

for Unity version 5.5 best way to avoid Immersive Mode in Android is to pass in the constructor not an Activity but to cast of the ApplicationContext to the Wrapper Context.

```
mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer((ContextWrapper) getApplicationContext());
```

That works because in the obfuscated UnityPlayer.class (in unity-classes.jar) there is a check of instance.

```
 private void h() {
     if(this.h instanceof Activity) {
        ((Activity)this.h).getWindow().setFlags(1024, 1024);
     }
 }
```

So if it's not an Activity the UnityPlayer.class doesn't set the flag.

Comment: it showing toolbar now after changing to ContextWrapper. but problem is that now camera view not rendering. Can you please give some suggestions?

Comment: Can you use kotlin extension functions to override this method?

Comment: Unluckly is not possible to override that method, because is private. You could do with a dirty solution: using reflection.

Comment: About the render camera problem:
the issue could be that if you don't use immersive mode, the layout is going to change its aspect ratio and resolution and maybe is not managed by camera SurfaceView
But, that is not tested and it is only a suggest. 
sorry for my approximate and uncertain answer

Answer (score 0):

Piotr answer is working for older version and  Lorenzo DM's answer also valid but

```
mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer((ContextWrapper) getApplicationContext());
```

not working in some devices. So Finally I've modify UnityPlayerActivity here is new solution

```
public class UnityPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer; // don't change the name of this variable; referenced from native code
    ActionBar actionBar;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FrameLayout unityContainer;

    // Setup activity layout
    @Override protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_unity_player);
        mappingWidgets();
        init();

    }

    void  mappingWidgets(){
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        unityContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.unity_container);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        unityContainer.addView(mUnityPlayer.getView(), 0, layoutParams);
        mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();

    }
    void init(){
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null)
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                onDestroy();
            }
        });
        setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));


    }


    @Override protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        setIntent(intent);
    }

    // Quit Unity
    @Override protected void onDestroy ()
    {
        mUnityPlayer.quit();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    // Pause Unity
    @Override protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        mUnityPlayer.pause();
    }

    // Resume Unity
    @Override protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mUnityPlayer.resume();
    }

    // Low Memory Unity
    @Override public void onLowMemory()
    {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mUnityPlayer.lowMemory();
    }

    // Trim Memory Unity
    @Override public void onTrimMemory(int level)
    {
        super.onTrimMemory(level);
        if (level == TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL)
        {
            mUnityPlayer.lowMemory();
        }
    }

    // This ensures the layout will be correct.
    @Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    // Notify Unity of the focus change.
    @Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }

    // For some reason the multiple keyevent type is not supported by the ndk.
    // Force event injection by overriding dispatchKeyEvent().
    @Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE)
            return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    // Pass any events not handled by (unfocused) views straight to UnityPlayer
    //@Override public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)     { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
    // Pass any events not handled by (unfocused) views straight to UnityPlayer
    @Override public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)     {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            finish();
            onDestroy();
            return true;
        }
        return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
    @Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)          { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
    /*API12*/ public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)  { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
}
```