# Is there any way to use UnityPlayerActivity as AppcompatActivity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am making unity plugins with android studio and I have problem here. Some SDK provides to make fragment with just `AppcompatActivity` but My `MainActivity`, exactly `UnityPlayerActivity` is not an `AppCompatActivity`. so it causes an error... Anyone can solve this problem?

Comment: could you post the error please?

Comment: @Lotan This is not related any error. But we can't use activity as an argument in those sdk which accept appcomatactivity or fragmentactivity as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about the SDK you're trying to interact with, it's hard to tell you exactly what to do to solve your problem. However, some background info about the classes might help you:

`UnityPlayerActivity` is a subclass of Android's `Activity` class. This is the main class used for modern Android activities.

`AppCompatActivity` is also a subclass of the `Activity` class, designed to let you use certain features (such as fragments) on older Android devices. From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity):

> Base class for activities that wish to use some of the newer platform
> features on older Android devices. Some of these backported features
> include:
>
> - Using the action bar, including action items, navigation modes and more with the setSupportActionBar(Toolbar) API.
> - Built-in switching between light and dark themes by using the Theme.AppCompat.DayNight theme and
>   AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(int) API.
> - Integration with DrawerLayout by using the getDrawerToggleDelegate() API.

So in OO terms:

- `UnityPlayActivity` is-a `Activity`
- `AppCompatActivity` is-a `Activity`
- `UnityPlayActivity` is not a `AppCompatActivity` (they have a sibling relationship).

If you absolutely need `AppCompatActivity`, one way to handle this is to modify the `UnityPlayActivity` code to extend `AppCompatActivity` instead. You can [see an example of that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44025258/28106).